# ODBC Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

I try to update a table, with the value of `OPC SIMULATIE:Configured Aliases.PLC1.RPM`
But then i get this:

`Executing ODBC update: update test set  where test = OPC SIMULATIE:Configured Aliases.PLC1.RPM`

```
ODBC Error: [[[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.11]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `test` = 'OPC SIMULATIE:Configured Aliases.PLC1.RPM'' at line 1 42000 1064]]
on: Could not ExecDirect: update test set  where `test` = 'OPC SIMULATIE:Configured Aliases.PLC1.RPM'

ODBC Error: [[[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.11]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `test` = 'OPC SIMULATIE:Configured Aliases.PLC1.RPM'' at line 1 42000 1064]]
on: update test set  where `test` = 'OPC SIMULATIE:Configured Aliases.PLC1.RPM'
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified what fields to update:

```
update test set where test = 'OPC SIMULATIE:Configured Aliases.PLC1.RPM'
```

should have something like:

```
update test set field='value' where test = 'OPC SIMULATIE:Configured Aliases.PLC1.RPM'
```

Comment: I thought so! But there comes the real problem, the ODBC driver sends it that way. Maybe an update will help! Thanks for your quick answer